# How to apply condition on child xpath from parent xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, siblings, xpath-1.0, ancestor

I wanted to click on the "waved off" button (child node) if status is "Pending" (parent node).

Then what will be the xpath in protractor ?

I've founded root xpath of waved off button but I'm not getting how to use that in coding.

if I approve first tr tag then it goes down and 2nd tr tag comes on top if it's pending. There are total 5 tr tags in my code.
and all tr tags are not fixed on their position. whenever I run my script I get pending tr tags on top .

```html
<div>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    <p> required </p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p> Pending </p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>
      <img>     </img>
      <div>
        <div>       </div>
        <div>       </div>
        <button> View Remark </button>
        <button> Waved off </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <p> required </p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p> Pending </p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>
      <img>     </img>
      <div>
        <div>       </div>
        <div>       </div>
        <button> View Remark </button>
        <button> Waved off </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I see some invalid HTML in the code you posted (`<img>       </img`). Is this really in the HTML document? If so, I would correct the markup errors first, since the document object model in the browser might not contain the same structure that you think it should.

Comment: `//tr[td/p[contains(text(), 'Pending')]]/td//button[contains(text(),'Waved off')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
//p[contains(text(), 'Pending')]/parent::td/following-sibling::*/descendant::*/button[contains(text(),'Waved off')]
```

Going forward please include the whole `<table>` tag contents into your question, the chance of getting more accurate advice will be much higher

[image]

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `..` expression to choose a parent node relative to a currently selected node in XPath. If you can get the "Pending" `<p>` tag, then you just need to go up 3 tags, and then find a button that contains "waved off":

```
//p[contains(., 'Pending')]/../../..//button[contains(., 'waved off')]
\________________________/  \_____/ \________________________________/
             |                 |                    |
            (1)               (2)                  (3)
            <p>          +--> <tr>              <button>
              Pending    |      <td>               waved off
            </p>         |        <p>            </button>
                         |          required
                         |        </p>
                         |      </td>
                         |      <td>
                         +----<-- <p>
                                    Pending
                                  </p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <div>
                                    <img>
                                    <div>
                                      <button>
                                        waved off
                                      </button>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
```

1. Find a `<p>` tag arbitrarily deep in the HTML document that contains the text "Pending".
2. From the `<p>` that contains the text "Pending", go up three parent nodes, which takes you to the `<tr>` tag.
3. From the `<tr>` tag, find a button that is a descendant of the `<tr>` tag that contains the text "wave off".

Answer (score 0):

Factually, there are 2 `<button>` with text as **Waved off** with respect to the `<p>` nodes with text as **Pending**. So locate the desired elements you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Xpath*:

  ```
  //p[contains(., 'Pending')]//following::td[1]//button[contains(., 'Waved off')]
  ```
- Snapshot:

[image: WavedOff]

**Note**: As mentioned above this *Locator Strategy* will identify 2 elements and as your usecase is to click on the desired element you have to induce a `waiter` for the *element to be clickable*